# 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem>' does not contain a definition for 'Where'

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I am getting below error with the following code:

Code:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
  var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(x => x.TemplateId == templateID).ToList();
}
```

Error:

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method
>   'Where' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Can anybody let me know the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have references to `System.LINQ`